# Renaming files in folder by it's date python

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I want to rename photos in folder by it's date. This is my python script.

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

folder_name = 'D:/Users/user/Desktop/Xiomi/100ANDRO/'
dir_list = [os.path.join(folder_name, x) for x in os.listdir(folder_name)]

for file in dir_list:
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file)
    date = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(file)).strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
    os.rename(os.path.basename(file), date + file_extension)

print(dir_list)
```

But I have an error:

```
$ python script.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
os.rename(os.path.basename(file), date + file_extension)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] ▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒▒ ▒▒▒▒: 
'DSC_0003.JPG' -> '2018_07_08_12_28_21.JPG'
```

The file is definitely in folder. Can you help me with it?

Comment: rename needs absolute paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you taking the base name from the target when the absolute path would be okay ?

`os.rename` works on files that *exist*. It works if you pass absolute paths provided that the files are located on the same drive. I'd do:

```
os.rename(file, os.path.join(folder_name,date + file_extension))
```

basically remove the basename, and add the folder name for the destination. Since the directory is the same for both, that'll work. And it's much cleaner than a dirty `os.chdir(folder_name)`

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you need to give `os.rename()` the absolute path to the file

```
os.rename(file, os.path.join(folder_name, date + file_extension))
```