# Python loop through directories

Tags: python, python-os

I am trying to use python library `os` to loop through all my subdirectories in the root directory, and target specific file name and rename them.
Just to make it clear this is my tree structure[image]

My python file is located at the root level.

What I am trying to do, is to target the directory `942ba` loop through all the sub directories and locate the file `000000` and rename it to `000000.csv`

the current code I have is as follow:

```
import os


root = '<path-to-dir>/942ba956-8967-4bec-9540-fbd97441d17f/'
for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for f in files:
        print(dirs)
        if f == '000000':
            dirs = dirs.strip(root)
            f_new = f + '.csv'
            os.rename(os.path.join(r'{}'.format(dirs), f), os.path.join(r'{}'.format(dirs), f_new))
```

But this is not working, because when I run my code, for some reasons the code strips the date from the subduers

[image]

can anyone help me to understand how to solve this issue?

Comment: Below shoule help you
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52485698/renaming-files-in-folder-by-its-date-python

Comment: `dirs.strip(root)` is throwing away part of the full pathname required to locate your files.  And what is the point of writing `r'{}'.format(dirs)` instead of just `dirs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient way to iterate through the folders and only select the files you are looking for is below:

```
source_folder = '<path-to-dir>/942ba956-8967-4bec-9540-fbd97441d17f/'
files = [os.path.normpath(os.path.join(root,f)) for root,dirs,files in os.walk(source_folder) for f in files if '000000' in f and not f.endswith('.gz')]
for file in files:
    os.rename(f, f"{f}.csv")
```

The list comprehension stores the full path to the files you are looking for. You can change the condition inside the comprehension to anything you need. I use this code snippet a lot to find just images of certain type, or remove unwanted files from the selected files.
In the for loop, files are renamed adding the `.csv` extension.

Answer (score 0):

I would use glob to find the files.

```
import os, glob
zdir = '942ba956-8967-4bec-9540-fbd97441d17f'
files = glob.glob('*{}/000000'.format(zdir))
for fly in files:
    os.rename(fly, '{}.csv'.format(fly))
```